# How do i use a dynamic array with char type

Tags: c++

So try to write a program that allows the user to range the number of rows in the program. I was unable to figure out how I was able to do so using a char array. I know the code works when I do a static array it's just trying to figure out how I can change it dynamically. I'm still new to c++ to please explain in beginner terms.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int ROW = 7;
const int COL = 4;

void printArray(char s[][COL], int rowsize);
void pickSeat(char s[][COL], int rowsize, int numberofseats);


int main()
{
    int index = 0;

    int size;

    cout << "How many row do you wany:"<<endl;
    cin >> size;

    int row = 1;
    int seats = 28;
    char *arr;
    arr = new char[size][4];

    arr[7][4] =
    {
        {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
        {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
        {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
        {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
        {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
        {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
        {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' }
    };

    char choice = 'y';

    while (tolower(choice) != 'n' && seats >= 0)
    {
        printArray(arr, row);
        pickSeat(arr, row, seats);

        printArray(arr, COL);
        cout << "Do want to ext? Enter anything to cotiune.(enter n to exit)";
        cin >> choice;



        seats--;
    }
    return 0;
}


void pickSeat(char s[][COL], int rowsize, int numberofseats)
{
    int r1, r2;


    cout << "Pick a seat enter row the colum.";
    cin >> r1;
    cin >> r2;

    if (s[r1 - 1][r2 - 1] == 'x')
    {
        cout << "this seat is taken" << endl;
        numberofseats++;

        pickSeat(s, rowsize, numberofseats);
    }
    else
    {
        s[r1 - 1][r2 - 1] = 'x';

    }

}

void printArray(char s[][COL], int rowsize)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        cout << rowsize << " ";

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            cout << s[i][j];
            /*if (j == 1)
            {*/

            /*  }*/
        }
        cout << endl;
        rowsize++;

    }
    rowsize = 1;
}
```

Comment: In C++, you don't use "dynamic arrays". Not for string nor for any other data. For strings use `std::string` and for other data use `std::vector`.

Comment: As a hint about one major problem with your current code (and which should prevent it from building, though its not clear if that's what you're asking about), the type of `char[size][4]` is not `char*` (the declared type of `arr`). That initialization of `arr` isn't correct either. Please invest in [some good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#3882829) and take classes.

Comment: Things will become much easier if you stop using C-style arrays

Answer (score 2):

Use Vectors

Vector is a sequential container to store elements and not index based.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    using namespace std;
    
    int main() {
    
      // initializer

 list
  vector<int> vector1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

  // uniform initialization
  vector<int> vector2{6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

  // method 3
  vector<int> vector3(5, 12);

  cout << "vector1 = ";

  // ranged loop
  for (const int& i : vector1) {
    cout << i << "  ";
  }

  cout << "\nvector2 = ";

  // ranged loop
  for (const int& i : vector2) {
    cout << i << "  ";
  }

  cout << "\nvector3 = ";

  // ranged loop
  for (int i : vector3) {
    cout << i << "  ";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo can use better `std::vector` or if you want array, there is `std::array(C++11)`. Better than array

Answer (score 1):

You show a great deal of confusion in your declaration(s) of `arr` and your attempt to allocate the shadowed version of `arr`, e.g.

```cpp
    char *arr;
    arr = new char[size][4];

     arr[7][4] =
    {
        {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
        {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
        {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
        {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
        {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
        {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
        {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' }
    };
```

In the snipped above, you attempt to allocate for the pointer `char *arr;` an array of `size` rows and `4` columns. You then turn around and declare `arr[7][4] =`  (or you access 1-past the last row and column) attempting to initialize the array.

You either allocate storage dynamically with `new` or you declare and initialize the array with automatic storage duration. Not both. (I actually think the confusion stems from your belief you could block-initialize `arr` after creating storage with `new` -- you can't)

Instead, just declare and initialize the array with automatic storage duration, e.g.

```cpp
  int seats = ROW * COL;
  char arr[ROW][COL] = {
      {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
      {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
      {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
      {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
      {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
      {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
      {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' }
  };
```

Note: you have already declared:

```cpp
const int ROW = 7;
const int COL = 4;
```

So don't use *MagicNumbers* `4` and `7` later in your code. Instead, use the constants you declared.

If you want a `7x4` array, then there is no need to worry about your `size` variable or dynamically allocating with `new`.

*Adjust the Number of Seats that Remain in `pickSeat()`*

The only time you change the seats available is in `pickSeat()`. Shis being C++, you can simply pass a reference to `seats` and update the value in `pickSeat()`, e.g.

```cpp
void pickSeat(char s[][COL], int& numberofseats)
{
  int r1, r2;

  for (;;) {  /* loop continually until no seats or 'n' entered */
    std::cout << "\nPick a seat, enter row & colum: ";
    std::cin >> r1;
    std::cin >> r2;
    
    if (std::cin.fail()) {
      std::cerr << " error: invalid int for r1 or r2.\n";
      std::cin.clear();
      std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
      continue;
    }
    
    if (r1 < 0 || ROW + 1 <= r1) {
      std::cerr << "error: r1 out of range, must be 0->" << ROW << ".\n";
      continue;
    }
    
    if (r2 < 0 || COL + 1 <= r2) {
      std::cerr << "error: r2 out of range, must be 0->" << COL << ".\n";
      continue;
    }
    
    if (s[r1 - 1][r2 - 1] == 'x') {
      std::cout << "  this seat is taken.\n";
    }
    else {
      s[r1 - 1][r2 - 1] = 'x';
      numberofseats--;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

The only time you reduce the number of seats available is when the requested seat is available to be assigned. If the seat is already assigned, you simply loop again and give the user a chance to pick a seat not already taken.

As with all input routines, you are better served by looping continually until the user provides valid input, and if not, handle the error, clear any error flag on the stream, remove any extraneous characters left in the input stream with `std::cin.ignore()`.

*Pass only your array to `printArray()`*

You defined `ROW` and `COL` and those values are available globally. So all you need to pass to your `printArray()` function is the array itself. You already know the number of `ROW` and `COL`, e.g.

```cpp
void printArray(char s[][COL]) {

  for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
    std::cout << i + 1 << " ";

    for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
      std::cout << s[i][j];
    }
    std::cout.put('\n');
  }
}
```

A complete example with the cleanups discussed above as well as additional validation in `pickSeat()` could be:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

const int ROW = 7;
const int COL = 4;

void printArray (char (*s)[COL]);
void pickSeat (char (*s)[COL], int& numberofseats);

int main()
{
  /*
  int size;

  std::cout << "How many row do you want: ";
  if (!(std::cin >> size)) {
    std::cerr << "invalid integer value.\n";
    return 1;
  }
  */

  int seats = ROW * COL;
  char arr[ROW][COL] = {
      {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
      {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
      {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
      {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
      {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
      {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
      {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' }
  };
  
  char choice = 'y';

  while (std::tolower(choice) != 'n' && seats >= 0) {
    printArray (arr);
    pickSeat(arr, seats);

    printArray(arr);
    std::cout << "\n[" << seats << "] remain\n" << 
                "Enter anything to cotiune. (n to exit) ";
    std::cin >> choice;
  }
  
  std::cout << "\n[" << seats << "] seats remain unfilled:\n";
  printArray(arr);
}


void pickSeat(char s[][COL], int& numberofseats)
{
  int r1, r2;

  for (;;) {  /* loop continually until no seats or 'n' entered */
    std::cout << "\nPick a seat, enter row & colum: ";
    std::cin >> r1;
    std::cin >> r2;
    
    if (std::cin.fail()) {
      std::cerr << " error: invalid int for r1 or r2.\n";
      std::cin.clear();
      std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
      continue;
    }
    
    if (r1 < 0 || ROW + 1 <= r1) {
      std::cerr << "error: r1 out of range, must be 0->" << ROW << ".\n";
      continue;
    }
    
    if (r2 < 0 || COL + 1 <= r2) {
      std::cerr << "error: r2 out of range, must be 0->" << COL << ".\n";
      continue;
    }
    
    if (s[r1 - 1][r2 - 1] == 'x') {
      std::cout << "  this seat is taken.\n";
    }
    else {
      s[r1 - 1][r2 - 1] = 'x';
      numberofseats--;
      break;
    }
  }
}

void printArray(char s[][COL]) {

  for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
    std::cout << i + 1 << " ";

    for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
      std::cout << s[i][j];
    }
    std::cout.put('\n');
  }
}
```

(**note:** your use of `size` was left commented out in case you did intend to use `new` in some other manner)

**Example Use/Output**

Running the code produces what appears to be the wanted behavior, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/char_array
1 ABCD
2 ABCD
3 ABCD
4 ABCD
5 ABCD
6 ABCD
7 ABCD

Pick a seat, enter row & colum: 4 2
1 ABCD
2 ABCD
3 ABCD
4 AxCD
5 ABCD
6 ABCD
7 ABCD

[27] remain
Enter anything to cotiune. (n to exit) y
1 ABCD
2 ABCD
3 ABCD
4 AxCD
5 ABCD
6 ABCD
7 ABCD

Pick a seat, enter row & colum: 4 3
1 ABCD
2 ABCD
3 ABCD
4 AxxD
5 ABCD
6 ABCD
7 ABCD

[26] remain
Enter anything to cotiune. (n to exit) y
1 ABCD
2 ABCD
3 ABCD
4 AxxD
5 ABCD
6 ABCD
7 ABCD

Pick a seat, enter row & colum: 2 1
1 ABCD
2 xBCD
3 ABCD
4 AxxD
5 ABCD
6 ABCD
7 ABCD

[25] remain
Enter anything to cotiune. (n to exit) y
1 ABCD
2 xBCD
3 ABCD
4 AxxD
5 ABCD
6 ABCD
7 ABCD

Pick a seat, enter row & colum: 2 4
1 ABCD
2 xBCx
3 ABCD
4 AxxD
5 ABCD
6 ABCD
7 ABCD

[24] remain
Enter anything to cotiune. (n to exit) n

[24] seats remain unfilled:
1 ABCD
2 xBCx
3 ABCD
4 AxxD
5 ABCD
6 ABCD
7 ABCD
```

An additional output of the array is printed at the end to show the final state of selected seats and the number of seats that remain unfilled.

Look things over. This looked to be the direction you were heading in, but there were some choices that could have been made one way or the other. Let me know if I misjudged your intent or if you need further help. There are many additional cleanups that can be implemented, this just reflects those where it was apparent you were a bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

Use vectors instead of arrays.
Vectors are basically dynamic arrays with the ability to resize itself automatically when an element is inserted or deleted

Comment: An example would be helpful: `std::vector<char>`